# Element is disappearing after animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a button alternates its visibility when a second button is clicked. For example, on the first click it slides from the right (outside the screen) to the position defined on layout file and on the second click it slides to the right. These animations also use fade in/out.

I'm currently using this code (click listeners ommited for the sake of simplicity):

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/unlock_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_lock_red"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

Java

```
//Hiding
mUnlockButton.animate()
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setDuration(600)
                        .translationX(50)
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                mUnlockButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        })
                        .start();

//Show
mUnlockButton.setAlpha(0f);
                mUnlockButton.setTranslationX(50);
                mUnlockButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mUnlockButton.animate()
                        .alpha(1.0f)
                        .setDuration(600)
                        .translationX(-50)
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                        .start();
```

After the third click (show, hide, then show again) the animation is run but the button disappears when the animation ends.

Why?

Comment: Found the error. I was setting the button's `translationX` before animation.